# gnuplot - alignment of horizontal key titles of different length

Tags: alignment, gnuplot

I am having difficulty with the alignment of the different key titles when placed horizontally, apparently due to the differing lengths in the titles.

Having two short plot titles (1st and 4th) and two longer titles (2nd and 3rd) it leaves a larger gap between the final two titles (presumably as it is setting the gaps between them all by the same maximum string length). I have searched but found no way to alter this.

A simplified example is shown below. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
set terminal postscript eps size 5.12,2.3 enhanced color "Helvetica" 12
set output 'example.eps'

set title 'Difficulty of Long and Short Title usage in Horizontal Keys' font "Helvetica, 20"

set key inside bottom center horizontal font "Helvetica, 20" width 1.8

set ylabel 'ylabel' font "Helvetica, 20" 
set xlabel 'xlabel' font "Helvetica, 20"  
set lmargin screen 0.10
set rmargin screen 0.95
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]

plot sin(x) title 'short', \
cos(x) title 'long title 1', \
-0.5 title 'long title 2', \
0.5 title 'short' w l ls 4
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: I don't see any way to solve this with the existing `set key` options. Do you have any dependency between one long and one short title? Maybe it would work out to have a `2x2` key (`set key maxcols 2`) with both short keys in the left column?

Comment: Many thanks for your response.  Unfortunately I am quite keen on keeping the order of the titles in the actual plot and would prefer keeping them in one row. This is obviously an aesthetic question, so not the end of the world but would be good to know if it is possible or not.  Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround for this would be to generate the first three graphs and the last one with two different plot commands in `multiplot` mode:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 5.12,2.3 enhanced color "Helvetica" 12
set output 'example.eps'

set title 'Difficulty of Long and Short Title usage in Horizontal Keys' font "Helvetica, 20"

set ylabel 'ylabel' font "Helvetica, 20" 
set xlabel 'xlabel' font "Helvetica, 20"  
set lmargin screen 0.10
set rmargin screen 0.95
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]

set bmargin screen 0.15
set tmargin screen 0.9

set multiplot
set key horizontal font "Helvetica, 20" width 1.8 at graph 0.4, graph 0.1 center maxrows 1
plot sin(x) title 'short', \
     cos(x) title 'long title 1', \
     -0.5 title 'long title 2'

unset title
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
unset border
unset tics
set key horizontal font "Helvetica, 20" width 1.8 at graph 0.84, graph 0.1 center maxrows 1
plot 0.5 title 'short' w l ls 4
unset multiplot
```

However, this requires some tweaking:

- Before the second `plot` you must remove title, labels, tics and border, otherwise the graph might look jagged because of different anti-aliasing
- To have the same margins you must also set fixed `tmargin` and `bmargin`
- You must position your keys manually

The above code gives you:
[image]

Now you must judge if its worth.

Answer (score -1):

You might use the `svg` terminal and make the adjustments by opening the svg file on inkscape.

Comment: Or use a png terminal and use a raster graphics editor, or postscript, and edit the source... You are kidding, right?